# How to rotate an image using Touch in HTML

Tags: html, image-rotation

Is anybody know how to rotate an image using Touch in HTML, CSS or JavaScript. I have attached the image for easy understanding. Please help me.Would really appreciate any suggestions.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YE7WP.png

Answer (score 3):

css3:

```
-ms-transform:rotate(30deg); /* IE 9 */
-moz-transform:rotate(30deg); /* Firefox */
-webkit-transform:rotate(30deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform:rotate(30deg); /* Opera */
```

you can take a look to w3school, and be care because the rotation is not supported for all browser.

http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_2dtransforms.asp

EDIT:

that image that you linked is not being rotated, he just change a image position:

take a look to this tutorial,

http://kyleschaeffer.com/best-practices/pure-css-image-hover/

Comment: Thanks for the answer...
But what I need exactly is when I touch and rotate an image to 90 deg it should hide and another image should be display on previous image...


http://i.stack.imgur.com/YE7WP.png

Comment: @user622978 If I understood, you want to make the rotation visible, if that so, you'll need to make it with JS, please take a look to this tutorial how to do that, ant let us know if it helped you:http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/